# ipad how to know keyboard has been hidden

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, hide

Im building an ipad app,

it haves some text fields that when tapped, move above the keyboard,

if a "calculate" button is tapped, keyboard and view, go down,

but if the user taps on the hide keyboard from the ipad [bottom right corner key of keyboard]

my view remains moved high,

so, how can i know programatically that the "hide keyboard" has been tapped?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the notification center for tracking the keyboard,

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didShow) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

//Resize your views in the below methods
- (void)didShow
{

}

- (void)didHide
{

}
```