# iOS event when keyboard hides

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to control, after keyboard is shown and done button is pressed, when keyboard hides. Which event is triggered when hides keyboard on iOS? Thank you

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=keyboard+hide

Comment: possible duplicate of [ipad how to know keyboard has been hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912246/ipad-how-to-know-keyboard-has-been-hidden)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes Use the following

```
//UIKeyboardDidHideNotification when keyboard is fully hidden
//name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification when keyboard is going to be hidden

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

And the `onKeyboardHide`

```
-(void)onKeyboardHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     //keyboard will hide
}
```

Comment: This will trigger at the moment of dismissal, not when the keyboard is fully hidden.

Comment: yes, correct, please check the updated answer, for fully hidden notification use `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know when the user press the Done button, you have to adopt the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, then in you View controller implement this method:

Swift 3:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // this will hide the keyboard
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

If you want to know simply when keyboard is shown or is hiding, use a `Notification` :

Swift 3:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow , object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide , object: nil)

func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    print("keyboard will show!")

    // To obtain the size of the keyboard:
    let keyboardSize:CGSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size

}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Keyboard will hide!")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can listen for a `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, it's sent whenever the keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: To be precise, the notification is sent BEFORE the keyboard is dismissed.